# The body too small even when I use a "clear" div

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my code and tell why things don't work out please. The blue line should be on the bottom of the page. The body seems to be really small even though I used clear divs. If you find what went wrong please explain the solution. I'm new in coding so an explanation will be really useful to me. Thank you on advance.

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    .clear {
     clear:both;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
     width:80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    header {
     margin-top:40px;
     border-bottom:1px solid black;
     padding-bottom:10px;
    }
    
    header img {
     float:left;
     width: 250px;
    }
    
    #socialmedia {
     float:right;
     padding:0;
     margin-top:-2px;
    }
    
    #socialmedia li {
     float:left;
     list-style-type:none;
     padding-left:10px;
    }
    
    li img {
     width:40px;
    }
    
    #listmenu {
     float:left;
     margin-top:80px;
     margin-right:5px;
    }
    
    #listmenu li {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom:40px;
     font-family:Arial;
     Font-size: 30px;
     border-right:1px solid black;
    }
    
    #leftmenu li:first-child {
     color:#3598db;
    }
    
    #right {
     float:right;
     width:60%;
    }
    
    #signupline {
     background-color:#3598db;
     height:50px;
     width:auto;
    }
    
    button {
     float:left;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Untitled Document</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
      </head>
    
      <body>
       <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
         <img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/>
         <ul id="socialmedia">
          <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="youtube.png" alt="youtube" /></a></li>
         </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
      </header>
    
    <div id="leftmenu">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="listmenu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>What's e-friendship</li>
    <li>Lanching Day</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clean"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="right">
    <h1>Welcome to e-Freindship</h1>
    <p>e-Friendship is the new unbelievable website where you can make new friends from all over thr world. Reading is a complex cognitive process of decoding symbols in order to construct or derive meaning (reading comprehension). Reading is a means of language acquisition, of communication, and of sharing information and ideas. Like all languages, it is a complex interaction between the text and the reader which is shaped by the reader’s prior knowledge, experiences, attitude, and language community which is culturally and socially situated. The reading process requires continuous practice, development, and refinement. In addition, reading requires creativity and critical analysis. Consumers of literature make ventures with each piece, innately deviating from literal words to create images that make sense to them in the unfamiliar places the texts describe. Because reading is such a complex process, it cannot be controlled or restricted to one or two interpretations. There are no concrete laws in reading, but rather allows readers an escape to produce their own products introspectively. This promotes deep exploration of texts during interpretation.[1] Readers use a variety of reading strategies to assist with decoding (to translate symbols into sounds or visual representations of speech) and comprehension. Readers may use context clues to identify the meaning of unknown words. Readers integrate the words they have read into their existing framework of knowledge or schema (schemata theory).</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="signupline">
     <p id="signuptext">Take your place and sign up</p>
      <button>Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `bottom of the page`? That it should be always on the bottom of the screen or that you just want that it is at last position of the page? Have you tried using `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`? or `position: fixed; bottom: 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try move the `clear` div out of  the `right` div:

```
<div id="right">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: It worked. But why "clear" has to be out of the <div id="right">...</div> ?

Comment: In fact no float elements surround the `clear` div, so it clears nothing...`clear` doesn't work for parent elements.